# Google play services e setInterval

Tags: android, gps

Estou tentando utilizar o google play service para pegar a posição do usuário.
O problema é o seguinte, tenho intervalo de tempo dinamico para o envio desta posição para o servidor. Contudo, o LocationClient não respeita este intervalo, independente do valor que ele possuir, a atualização da posição se dá em um intervalo fixo de 5 s.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

O código:

```
private LocationClient locationClient;

public void iniciarBusca(long updateInterval, long fastestInterval) {
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(updateInterval);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(fastestInterval);

    locationClient = new LocationClient(activity, this, this);      
    locationClient.connect();
}

public void disconectar() {
    try {
        locationClient.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual o valor que você está colocando para o `fastestInterval`?

Comment: Está dinâmico, é o mesmo valor que é calculado para para o updateInterval.

Comment: Quais são os valores que você espera para esses dois campos? Quando você usa o fastestInterval, está falando para o Play Services que o seu Location é dinamico, ou seja, ele é calculado baseado no estado de bateria, rede, precisão etc., o que pode estar acontecendo é que o Play Services está calculando esse tempo para você.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá minha primeira dica é você colocar o `connect` e o `disconnect` dentro do `onPause` e do `onResume` assim:

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationClient.disconnect();
    }
```

E sobre o intervalo eu não entendi muito bem a sua intenção pois o valor de `updateInterval` e `fastestInterval` é igual a zero, pois você não colocou valor para eles apenas setou eles como `setInterval` e `setFastestInterval`.

Me corrija se eu estiver errado.
Um Abraço.